# can a photons energy state be altered with magnetic force?

Tags: thermodynamics, particle-physics, spectroscopy, solar-wind

with respect to sunlight, is there any way to use a magnet to alter the energy impact of sunlight?
more or less energy, or hotter vs cooler?
All spectrums considered. visable, xray, gamma.
Can a magnet be used to effect sunlights impact on matter?

[Note](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2015/05/150514085655.htm)

Comment: Well you can accelerate the magnet to relativisitc speeds away from the light source, then the light's impact energy will be reduced due to doppler.
Although you could do that with any object.